# jQuery mobile menu works slow on mobile phone (but works fast when tested on desktop browsers)

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

This is my site: https://robothabanera.github.io/mogo/

My aim is to get the mobile menu to work smoothly on my **mobile phone**.
The issue appears in **mobile phone** namely I get some chopping behavior of slide in/slide out animation in mobile menu and I can't pinpoint what is causing the issue.

I would be grateful if somebody could access this site through mobile phone to see what I mean.

It is best to check the styles in script.js :

```
 //smoothscroll
$(".c-nav .c-main-menu .c-main-menu__link").on("click", function (e) {

                var currLink = $(this); 
                if (currLink.hasClass("trala")) {


                } else {
                    $("div.object1").remove();
                }

    if ($(window).width()<=1199) {

        e.preventDefault();
        $("html,body").animate({
            scrollTop: $($.attr(this, "href")).offset().top -60
        }, 1000, function() { 

            $(".c-main-menu").animate({"left": "-200px"}, 
            { duration: 200, queue: false });

            $("html,body").animate({"left": "0px"},
            {duration:200, quee: false});

    });



} else if ($(window).width() > 1199) {


    $("html,body").unbind("animate");


}

});
```

Comment: typo `"quee"`  .

Comment: ok I changed "quee" to "queue" and nothing changed. I would be grateful if somebody could access this site through mobile phone to see what I mean.

Comment: Well that url returns like 100 404s.

Comment: I removed the images and fonts (as you can see on the site) to see whether images or fonts were causing the issue. Obviously with images and fonts the issue was still present.

Comment: Have the same results on both desktop and mobile. So please give some more details of the issue.
Could be the problem connected to a low-performance mobile device ?

Comment: I am using inbuit HTC one browser. Through be told when I acces the site through dolphin browser (which is NOT inbuil HTC one browser, dolphin is an additional browser which I downloaded on my smartphone) on my HTC one the menu works smoothly as expected though on dolphin other issues arrise like not working grayscale filter etc.